# Ember can't find model when URL is keyed in directly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 1.4 with EmberData beta 7.  My application has the routes and models shown below:

```
 App.Router.map(function () {
     this.resource('strats', {path: "/"}, function() {
         this.route('strat', {path: "/strat/:strat_id"});
     });
 });

 App.StratsStratRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find(params.strat_id);
    }
 });

 var attr = DS.attr;
 var belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;
 var hasMany = DS.hasMany;

 App.StratLeg = DS.Model.extend({
     legName: attr(),
     quantity: attr(),
     strat: belongsTo('strat')
 });

 App.Strat = DS.Model.extend({
     stratName: attr(),
     stratLegs: hasMany('stratLeg', {async:true})
 });
```

I can transition into the strats.strat route via link-to fine.  So for example, if I transition into the strats.strat route via link-to for id="dd-put", URL displays

```
http://localhost:8000/em.yaws#/strat/dd-put
```

and everything works.  But now if I hit the refresh button, or type in that same URL after first transitioning to a different route, then I get this error message on the browser console and nothing displays:

```
 Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for 'dd-put'
   at new Error (native)
   at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-1.4.0.js:844:19)
   at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-data-beta7.js:9762:33)
   at Ember.Object.extend.findAll (http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-data-beta7.js:9364:21)
   at Ember.Object.extend.find (http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-data-beta7.js:9046:23)
   at App.StratsStratRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model (http://localhost:8000/js/app/ed.js:47:27)
   at superWrapper [as model] (http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-1.4.0.js:1239:16)
   at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.deserialize (http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-1.4.0.js:35901:19)
   at http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-1.4.0.js:32521:57
   at http://localhost:8000/js/scripts/ember-1.4.0.js:33000:19
```

Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Can we see your `StratsStratRoute`?

Comment: GJK, thanks for the big hint.  I posted the original, which was causing my problem.  When I changed the model hook to:     

this.store.find('strat', params.strat_id);

Everything worked fine.